# When using quartz scheduler in a java web app (struts2), where do i configure the jobs?

Tags: java, struts2, background, backgroundworker, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to integrate quartz scheduler into a struts2 web app. Just wondering *where* you configure the jobs? I think the best place would be to put their details in the quartz.properties, but i cannot find the documentation that shows how to do this.

All i can find is examples of how to programmatically create the jobs, but if i have to do that then i don't really see any advantage over simply using a java.util.Timer... Plus, in a web app, i can't think of a good place to put run-once startup code.

Any 'best practices' advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried using spring to instantiate a singleton bean, and in the constructor of the bean class to configure the jobs, however this constructor fires too early - it is before the quartz listener gets a chance to start up. Ideas?

Comment: Okay i've gotten around this by putting the quartz listener above the spring one in the web.xml. So, i guess it works, but it 'feels wrong' - is there a more 'best practices' way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah-ha: i think this is what i'm after:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/cookbook/JobInitPlugin.html

Basically, lets me configure jobs without code. Very neat and tidy.

Comment: I know this is old, but the link seems to be broken now.

Comment: the info is available on the below link - http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'configure the jobs' do you mean stuff like setting up how often they're run?

We use a database table (we are also using hibernate) - this allows for cron-like scheduling and you can change scheduling without having to redeploy anything.

This link might be useful as it covers a few different ways to approach the problem:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-quartz/

Comment: When i say 'configure the jobs' i mean scheduling them to run. Can this be done straight in the quartz.properties? Seems to me to be a logical place to do it.